# dropdown showing differently on firefox mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser

I have a website where I have issues with the Firefox Mobile styling. The issues are my dropdown menus that are showing correctly on all browsers as a dropdown, but on firefox mobile its showing ALL entries from the dropdown. The code is the same!

Please find attached 2 screenshots from my mobile phone (left is on chrome which is correct, and right one is from firefox). [picture for comparison: chrome mobile vs. firefox mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpcki.png)

```html
<div class="multiselect-box clearfix">
    <select name="job_sector[]" id="job_sector1" multiple="multiple" size="15">
        <option value="Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources">Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources</option>
        <option value="Architecture and Construction">Architecture and Construction</option>
        <option value="Arts, Audio/Video Technology and Communications">Arts, Audio/Video Technology and Communications</option>
        <option value="Business Management and Administration">Business Management and Administration</option>
        <option value="Education and Training">Education and Training</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Government and Public Administration">Government and Public Administration</option>
        <option value="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</option>
        <option value="Human Resource">Human Resource</option>
        <option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
        <option value="Hospitality and Tourism">Hospitality and Tourism</option>
        <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="Law, Public Safety, Corrections and Security">Law, Public Safety, Corrections and Security</option>
        <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
        <option value="Marketing, Sales and Service">Marketing, Sales and Service</option>
        <option value="Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics">Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Transportation, Distribution and Logistics">Transportation, Distribution and Logistics</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: how about some css and js? html has nothing to do with that

Comment: And learn to add code not just copy paste its off screen :O

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="multiselect-box clearfix">
  <select name="job_sector[]" id="job_sector1" multiple="multiple" size="15">
  <option value="Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources">Agriculture, Food and Natural Resources</option>
                                                                      <option value="Architecture and Construction">Architecture and Construction</option>
                                                                      <option value="Arts, Audio/Video Technology and Communications">Arts, Audio/Video Technology and Communications</option>
                                                                      <option value="Business Management and Administration">Business Management and Administration</option>
                                                                      <option value="Education and Training">Education and Training</option>
                                                                      <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                                                                      <option value="Government and Public Administration">Government and Public Administration</option>
                                                                      <option value="Business Analyst">Business Analyst</option>
                                                                      <option value="Human Resource">Human Resource</option>
                                                                      <option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
                                                                      <option value="Hospitality and Tourism">Hospitality and Tourism</option>
                                                                      <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
                                                                      <option value="Law, Public Safety, Corrections and Security">Law, Public Safety, Corrections and Security</option>
                                                                      <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
                                                                      <option value="Marketing, Sales and Service">Marketing, Sales and Service</option>
                                                                      <option value="Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics">Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics</option>
                                                                      <option value="Transportation, Distribution and Logistics">Transportation, Distribution and Logistics</option>                                                              
  </select>
</div>
```

```css
.responsive-mobile-filter .slider-bar-color {
  background-color: #edf3f5;
}

#responsive-mobile-filter .filter-title {
  padding: 5px 10px 15px;
}

#responsive-mobile-filter .filter.shadow {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#responsive-mobile-filter .box .multiselect-box select {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

#responsive-mobile-filter .box .multiselect-box select option {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  /* border: 1px solid #c4c4c4; */
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#responsive-mobile-filter .box .multiselect-box #job_sector1 option {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.filter form {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-right .btn.job-btn {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fixed .text-right .btn.job-btn {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```